# Why is are my inputs not taking up the full width with of my flexbox container

Tags: html, css, forms, vue.js, sass

I cant figure out why my top three inputs are not taking up the full width, can someone help me? or perhaps give me a better overall setup so that it's 
more responsive.

[image]

Here's my contact form scss:

```css
&__contact-form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 3rem;
  &__input-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    &__input-box {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: 1;
      & label {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
      }
      & input {
        height: 3rem;
        padding: 1.5rem;
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 3rem;
        border: 0.15rem solid #e51010;
      }
    }
  }
  & label {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
  }
  & textarea {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    resize: none;
    min-height: 60%;
    width: auto;
    border: 0.15rem solid #e51010;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <div class="contact-container">
    <h2>Talk to Us!</h2>
    <form action="#" class="contact-container__contact-form">
      <div class="contact-container__contact-form__input-row">
        <div class="contact-container__contact-form__input-row__input-box">
          <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="full-name" id="FullName" placeholder="John Doe" />
        </div>
        <div class="contact-container__contact-form__input-row__input-box">
          <label for="subject">Subject</label>
          <input type="text" name="subject" id="Subject" placeholder="Booking Enquiry" />
        </div>
        <div class="contact-container__contact-form__input-row__input-box">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" placeholder="hello@me.com" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="Message" placeholder="How can we help?"></textarea>
    </form>
    <button class="contact-container__send-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `flex:1` to the input boxes on top and that doesn't work. The closest I have gotten is by using `justify-content: space-evenly` however it's still not fully there.

The issue could also be the `textarea` and not the above three inputs. If I apply `width: 100%` to the texarea, it goes way outside of the whole form.

HERE IS THE CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/squishyboots19996/pen/oNjawrv

Comment: can you share html code as well?

Comment: @Manjuboyz just added it!

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob sorry forgot to mention I'm using Vue.js, it applies the closing slash automatically

Comment: @squish the code gives me different design on adding it in snippet! is there a way you can recreate the issue for us? I created a code snippet behalf of you and that is how it looks!

Comment: Someone at Vue should read the HTML standard.

Comment: @Manjuboyz added a codepen with the problem recreated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gap because you specified a width:90% on inputs but their containers do not care about that, thei just fill their flex parent's width. Input element's width is always tricky anyway.

What you can do:

- Remove width rule on inputs
- On __input-box remove the flex-grow rule, set flex: 0 1 33% to limit the width (and create gaps) and remove the align-items rule so the inputs are stretched
- Set justify-content: space-between on __input-row

Like:

```
&__input-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  &__input-box {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 1 33%;

    & label {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }

    & input {
      height: 3rem;
      padding: 1.5rem;
      font-size: 3rem;
      border: 0.15rem solid #e51010;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an edited example: https://codepen.io/rndmerle/pen/jObeaMV

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. All working now! Element's width will always trip me up. Thanks again